# Kivy: screen defined in kvlang, how to add to screenmanager in python?

Tags: python, kivy

When you have a screenmanager with one screen, in kvlang:

```
<ScreenManagement>:
    ScreenOne:

<ScreenOne>:
    name: 'First'
    id: screen1


<ScreenTwo>:
    name: 'Second'
    id: screen2
```

And as can be seen, you also have a second screen defined, but it is not added to the screenmanager.

How do you add it with python? (I want to do it based on some condition from a config file)

I know I can add a widget to the screenmanager with `add_widget()` but I don't know how to reference the ScreenTwo from python.

I tried with ids but I get an keyError with this code:

```
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        def setup(*args):
            if True:    #under some condition, I want to add ScreenTwo
                #this does not work: KeyError
                screen_widget = App.get_running_app().root.ids['screen2']   
                self.add_widget(screen_widget)

        Clock.schedule_once(setup)
```

[Minimal working example code](http://pastebin.com/1cvGkPdc)

Comment: The `ids` list is visible only within a rule the `id` was defined. It is not global.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a few things wrong. First the things in `<` and `>` are called rules. These rules govern how the class is made whenever you invoke `ScreenOne()` in Python or in kv. Second, you are not able to add an id to a rule then access that id from a root widget. The correct way to do it is in my kv file. You move the id into the `<ScreenManagement>` rule. Lastly, you can always see what is going on with your kv file by doing a `print self.children`.

```
kvlang = '''
<ScreenManagement>:
    ScreenOne:
        id: screen1


<ScreenOne>:
    name: 'First'


<ScreenTwo>:
    name: 'Second'

'''


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ScreenManagement,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        Clock.schedule_once(self.setup)

    def setup(self,*args):
        if True:    #under some condition, I want to add ScreenTwo
            print self.children, self.current
            self.add_widget(ScreenTwo())
            self.current = 'Second'
            print self.children, self.current
            print self.ids
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got it working! One additional question: In the code you posted, where would you define the id of ScreenTwo ? You cannot do it in the ScreenManagement rule without instantiating ScreenTwo, can you? I know I probably don't need the id for the screen since I can just reference it with `screen_manager_widget.get_screen('name_of_screen')` but I was just wondering, in case I do need it.

Answer (score 0):

First, in your `kv` file, make sure `ScreenTwo` is a subclass of `Screen`: `<ScreenTwo@Screen>:`. Second, the angle brackets indicate a rule rather than an actual instantiation. It just means that if an object matching the rule is instantiated, it will get these properties. To instantiate an instance of `ScreenTwo` in your Python code, use [`Factory`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.factory.html?highlight=factory#module-kivy.factory):

```
screen_widget = Factory.ScreenTwo()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, the `<ScreenTwo@Screen>` notation is an alternative to defining it in your python file I assume?
`class ScreenTwo(Screen):
 pass`
In the answer of goCards no Factory was used, I tried with and without and both work. Is there any advantage using `Factory` that I should know of?

Comment: @Sebastian That's true. The main advantage I can think of is that it reduces clutter - there is only one location of definition. Of course this only works if one doesn't have declare additional methods on the class (but quite often that's not necessary, and even then it's easy to move the definition over)